# Center of Lie group and Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g} = T_eG$ its Lie algebra (where $e \in G$ is the neutral element). Denote $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ the center of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $Z(g)$ the center of $G$. I've read the following statement but don't see how to prove it:
$$Z(\mathfrak{g}) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow Z(G) \text{ is zero dimensional.}$$
I'm mainly interested in the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, as this is used in a corollary of the Bonnet-Myers theorem in the text I'm reading.

Now, my knowledge of Lie groups is very basic. For instance, I guess that the dimension of $Z(G)$ means its dimension as a manifold. So I would think that $Z(G)$ is a submanifold of $G$. But how do I even see this in general?

According to this question [When is the Lie algebra of the center of Lie group the center of its Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618431/when-is-the-lie-algebra-of-the-center-of-lie-group-the-center-of-its-lie-algebra), it seems to be difficult to find conditions when $Z(\mathfrak{g}) = Z(G)$ holds in general, however the statement above looks more simple.

**Would someone be able to prove the above equivalence?**

Comment: So there might be easier ways to do this, but do you know the fact that if two vector fields on a manifold have Lie bracket equal to zero, then their flows commute?

Comment: Or if you only care about matrix groups, we could use $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are commuting matrices.

Comment: Well, technically no, I don't know the fact that if two vector fields on a manifold have zero Lie bracket then their flows commute. Since you've mentioned it, I've quickly researched it now, although I can't say I fully understand the proof. If you have an easy way of showing the statement I'm interested in using this, please go ahead. I would also be interested in a proof that doesn't use it however.  And, I'm interested in general Lie groups, not just matrix groups.

Comment: I am probably generating more confusions here, but aren't the elements from each set different? One takes elements from $G$ and one select elements from the Lie Algebra $\frak{g}$

Comment: @Nameless Yes, you're right... Now I'm a little bit confused by the other question I'm referencing to...

Comment: @TomBombadil, I have no idea what their definition of the center is in that question because I am pretty sure $Z(\mathfrak{g}   ) = \{ X \in \mathfrak{g} : [X,Y] = 0, \forall Y \in \mathfrak{g}  \}$

Comment: What about the correspondence between subalgebras of $\frak{g}$ and subgroups of $G$?

Comment: As mentioned, my knowledge of Lie group theory is really very basic. It seems that this question is more difficult than I initially thought it was. If anyone has a good reference for this, it would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer for $G$ connected.

Okay, for $Y\in \frak{g}$, you can show that the flow on $G$ given by the vector field, $Y$, is given by multiplication by elements of $e^{tY}, (t\in \mathbb{R})$. If $X\neq 0$, is in the center, then its flow commutes with the flow associated to all other members of $\frak{g}$ i.e. $e^{tX}$ commutes with $e^{tY}$ for all $Y\in \frak{g}$.  The set $\{e^{tY}: t\in \mathbb{R}, Y\in \frak{g}\}$ contains an open neighborhood of the identity, so it generates $G$, since $G$ is connected.  So $e^{tY}$ commutes with a subset that generates $G$, hence it commutes with all elements of $G$.  Hence $e^{tY}$ is in the center of $G$.  So $Z(G)$ contains a one-dimensional sub manifold, hence is not zero-dimensional.

I realize this probably uses more Lie-group theory than you had hoped, and maybe theres a more elementary way to do it, but i don't immediately see it.

**Edit** :Maybe there's an easier way to see that $X\in Z(\frak{g})$ implies $e^{tX}\in Z(G)$: Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}, t\mapsto L_{e^{tY}\ast} \circ R_{e^{-tY}\ast }(X_e)$.  Then prove that $\gamma'(0)=[X,Y]$ (this requires the interpretation of the bracket as the Lie derivative). So if $X$ is in the center, then $\gamma'(s)= L_{e^{sY}_\ast }\circ R_{e^{-sY}_\ast }(0)=0$ (since $ L_{e^{(s+t)Y}\ast}= L_{e^{sY} \ast} \circ L_{e^{tY} \ast}$ and likewise for $X$).  But this implies $\gamma = X_e$ is constant.  So $e^{tY}e^{uX}e^{-tY} = e^{uX}$ for all $t, u\in \mathbb{R}$, which says all $e^{uX}$ commute with all $e^{tY}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand this proof modulo 2 things: The fact that if two vector fields have Lie bracket zero then their flows commute (as mentioned before), and the fact that an open neighbourhood of the identity generates G if G is connected. For the second statement however, I found a nice proof here: [a neighbourhood of identity U generates G where G is a connected lie group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282442/a-neighbourhood-of-identity-u-generates-g-where-g-is-a-connected-lie-group)

Comment: So, I'm happy with your answer, as long as I know that the general statement is not immediate and somewhat difficult to prove:)

Comment: You're welcome.  The first statement is proved in John Lee's book on smooth manifolds.  However I've edited the post to include a proof that doesn't use this fact.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain the fact in question with Lie theory which mostly appears very early in books of the topic, but yet isn't easy.

The center of $G$ is the set $Z(G) = \{g \in G \ \vert \ gh = hg \ \forall h \in G\}$. To tackle the equivalence, you were right with what $0$-dimensional in this  case even means; it means $Z(G)$ is $0$-dimensional as an embedded submanifold of $G$. That is true since $Z(G) = \ker(Ad)$ is a closed subgroup and thus an embedded Lie-subgroup of $G$ (this is not easy to prove!).

Per definition, $Z(\mathfrak{g}) = \{v \in \mathfrak{g} \ \vert \ [v,w] = 0 \ \forall w \in \mathfrak{g}\}$. But one can also look at $T_eZ(G)$, and yes, they agree: $T_eZ(G) =  Z(\mathfrak{g})$ (which is easy to see knowing that $Z(G) = \ker(Ad)$).

As a $0$-dimensional (embedded) submanifold of $G$, $Z(G)$ is a discrete subset of $G$. It is now clear that $Z(G)$ is $0$-dimensional iff $Z(G) = T_eZ(G) = 0$.

And by the way; one can also show that
$$Z(G) = G \Longleftrightarrow Z(\mathfrak{g}) = \mathfrak{g}.$$